# Mapping column space to row space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

We have that for any matrix A, that dim(Row(A)) = dim(col(A)). So it stands to reason that we may expect that there exists a bijection between these two spaces. In the case that A is square and invertible, I have managed to construct this mapping:

$$A^T A^{-1} c_i = (r_i)^T$$

where $c_i, r_i$ refer respectively to the $i$'th column and row vector of A.

But what if A is not invertible and not square? Then such a mapping should still exist due to the dimensions of the row and column space still being the same. Is it just not a unique mapping? How can we construct this mapping from the respective column vectors to the respective row vectors without relying on the inverse existing?

Comment: It’s easy to give a linear bijection from the column space to the row space. I have no idea what you mean by your last sentence.

Comment: How would you construct it?

Comment: Just use $A^\top$.